# Does S.H.I.E.L.D. know who Ant-Man is?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

At the end of the Ant-Man movie

> an entire building blows up in an unusual "shrinkplosion"

also

> a large ant & gigantic thomas the train engine burst out of a house in full view of local police

In light of the fact that in the 80's S.H.I.E.L.D. knew about Pym's technology, and probably was aware of Darren Cross's recent research efforts, wouldn't these two incidents lead to at least an investigation of Dr. Pym and/or Hope van Dyne, even assuming none of the knowledgeable parties (like Paxton) give them away?

Also, if

> the Falcon sees Scott Lang without his mask off before their fight

it seems reasonable to think that he could use video data from his A.R. glasses of Scott's face to figure out who he is using super S.H.I.E.L.D. facial recognition technology or even [plain-old-FBI-face-recognition](http://gcn.com/articles/2012/08/20/fbi-facial-recognition-software-open-to-police.aspx), considering that Scott would be in the system from his prison time.

Finally, at the end of the movie:

> the Falcon gets in contact with Scott.  Does he know his identity, then?

So, my question is really two questions:

1. Are the perpetrators of the events of Ant-Man known to S.H.I.E.L.D? If they are not, wouldn't some part of the government (FBI?) be investigating at least the first aforesaid unusual ocurence?
2. Is Ant-Man's identity known to Falcon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Given the propensity for intelligence by SHIELD, particularly where metahumans or specialized technology is concerned, it wouldn't take long for SHIELD to know who Ant-Man was especially since Pym's daughter Hope and Pym's company were involved.

- Or in this case, Pym's former company since it was reduced in what was certainly "an industrial accident" to nothing.
- And given the Falcon's glasses, the criminal database SHIELD has access to and the fact that Scott Lang started this movie behind bars, it shouldn't take them over three minutes to get his name, address and shoe size. Not a guess, a certainty.
- It is hinted Ant-Man may even be on the potential roster by Falcon, but it's nice and vague to keep people guessing.

Comment: Exactly!  Are there any evidences as of yet that they do?

Comment: And with the glasses, yeah that's what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

**We don't know if SHIELD know about Scott Lang.**

Thanks to the fractured nature of SHIELD at the moment and the lack of any new information since the release of *Ant-Man*, we simply have no way of knowing if Director Coulson is aware of the events of *Ant-Man* or who is responsible.

With certainty we can say that SHIELD as an organisation have information on Dr Hank Pym and his Pym Particles thanks to the fact he worked with them in the 1980's, but that doesn't mean that they know who the new Ant-Man is as Scott has kept his identity secret from everyone other than a few close friends, Hank Pym, Hope Van Dyne and his ex-wife's new husband, Jim Paxton. I find it unlikely that any of these characters would inform on Scott Lang to SHIELD, even if SHIELD were a legally recognised authority at this point in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (see: *Captain America: The Winter Solider*, *Agents of SHIELD*).

---

**Sam 'The Falcon' Wilson doesn't know who Scott Lang is... yet.**

We see a fight between Scott and Sam in *Ant-Man* after Scott attempts to steal a signal distruptor from an old Stark warehouse, which has since been converted into the Avengers facility seen at the end of *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

During this fight, Scott takes his mask off in order to speak to Sam face to face. In *Ant-Man*, Sam is using some kind of heads up display that locates Scott when he has shrunk - this may have had a recording facility, meaning that Sam might have been able to record Scotts face in order to help him find Scott later.

Even if that isn't the case, we see at the end of *Ant-Man* that Sam is searching for Scott, this information making its way to Scott through Luis in one of his monologues. At this stage it would seem that Sam doesn't know who Scott actually is yet.

However, the second post-credits scene in *Ant-Man* shows us;

> Steve 'Captain America' Rogers and Sam 'The Falcon' Wilson have successfully located (trapped?) Bucky 'The Winter Solider' Barnes after searching for him since *Captain America: The Winter Solider*.

A hushed conversation gives us snippets of information about what the next Marvel Cinematic Universe film, *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, has in store for us, including an exchange between Steve and Sam that has Sam saying that he "might know a guy" - a reference to Scott's involvement in *Captain America: Civil War*.

This has since been confirmed by the cast list for *Captain America: Civil War* (which includes Paul Rudd, who plays Scott Lang) and the recently showcased footage from *Captain America: Civil War* that was shown at D23, which included a clip of Scott meeting some of the Avengers for the first time.

**This means that at some point between *Ant-Man* and the end of *Captain America: Civil War*, Sam 'The Falcon' Wilson will learn the identity of Scott Lang, and presuambly fight alongside him.**

Answer (score 1):

### If they know about Hank, they know about Scott

SHIELD obviously knows all about the original Ant-Man, aka Hank Pym, because he used to work for them. Given the unique phenomena, and the fact that it's all happening in Hank's hometown and around his old corporate headquarters, Hank's involvement is a no-brainer.

As for the identity of the *new* Ant-Man, Scott wasn't being terribly sneaky around Hank's house.  They trained in the back yard, and had chats in Hope's car outside.  A few satellite photos of Hank's house are all anyone would need to notice "the new guy" Hank's been hanging out with, a young and athletic guy with a history of ethically-motivated lawbreaking, and from there the connection is obvious.

The only stumbling block is the dissolution of SHIELD: it's unclear how many records of Hank Pym's adventures survived.  Clearly Hydra knows about him, but do Coulson and the loyal remnants of SHIELD?  Only time will tell.

But if SHIELD knows about the Hank Pym connection to Ant-Man, the rest is child's play.